# CKEDITOR values show in 1 line in the console log result

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am creating CKeditor function. Now my problem is I cannot get the value in the CKeditor textarea. I try to console log to show the result, it cannot cannot follow html to show like below the picture:

[image: output]

Below is my coding:

```html
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">This is sample text</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
            height: 300,
           // enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
            filebrowserUploadUrl: "/eokclaim/app/ajaxfile.php?type=file",
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: "/eokclaim/app/ajaxfile.php?type=image"
        } );

    function updateDiv(){
       var editorText = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
       console.log(editorText);
    }
</script>
```

I want the expected result in console log are (I want the console log result show in 1 line) :

```html
<p>Picture 1:</p><br /><p><img alt="" src="https://www.abc.com.my/folder/app/uploads/blue-pin.png" style="height:100px; width:100px" /></p><br /><p>Picture 2:</p><br /><p><img alt="" src="https://www.abc.com.my/folder/app/uploads/1.png" style="height:34px; width:100px" /></p>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: If editorText is a string, have you tried simply removing lines breaks ? Like `editorText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");`.

Comment: I want to keep the html to store in variable then pass to the backend

Comment: You ask how to show a multiline text (this html is text) in one line. I think my fist comment answer the question. You can still keep it in the variable and pass it to the backend as well.

Comment: Ok. May I know how to add your code in my code?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove line breaks, you can use `replace` function. Your code would look like :

```
function updateDiv(){
   var editorText = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
   console.log(editorText);
}
```

If `getData()` is returning a string as I think, it should work.